# al llenar el fomulario le doy siguiente y no me pasa al paso 2

Tags: jquery, html5

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Prueba de orientación profesional</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/clean-blog.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Estilos del sitio web -->
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>


    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="brand pull-left" href="#">
                <img src="http://www.politecnicojic.edu.co/images/logo/logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive logo logo-poli"> </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          Menu
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Programas.html">Programas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Prueba.html">Prueba</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <br><br><br> 
     <section class="container py-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <center><h2>Prueba de Orientación Profesional</h2></center>
                <ul id="tabsJustified" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a  data-target="#paso1" class="nav-link small text-uppercase active"><b>PASO 1 - REGISTRO</b></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a data-target="#paso2" href="#paso2" class="nav-link small text-uppercase "><b>PASO 2 - PRUEBA</b></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a  data-target="#paso3" href="#paso3" class="nav-link small text-uppercase"><b>PASO 3 - RESULTADOS</b></a></li>
                    <!--data-toggle="tab" ..... para ir a  los link ...  href="" -->
                </ul>
                <br>
                <div id="tabsJustifiedContent" class="tab-content">
                    <div id="paso1" class="tab-pane fade active show">
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                        <fieldset>

                        <!-- Form Name - si la respuesta es no permitir pasar al siguiente paso -->
                        <legend><b><center>Registrar Información</center></b></legend>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="Training"><center>¿Desea suminitrar sus datos al portal web para enviarle información en el futuro?</label>
                              <div class="col-md-4"> 
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-0">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training" id="Training-0" value="si" checked="">
                                  Si
                                </label> 
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-1">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training" id="Training-1" value="no">
                                  No
                                </label>
                              </div>
                            </div></center>
                            <center>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <!--<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Nombre">Nombre</label>-->  
                              <div class="col-md-4">
                              <input id="Nombre" name="Nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control input-md" required="">
                                
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <!--<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Apellido">Apellido</label>-->  
                                  <div class="col-md-4">
                                  <input id="Apellido" name="Apellido" type="text" placeholder="Apellido" class="form-control input-md" required="">
                                    
                                  </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <!--<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Correo">Correo</label>-->  
                                  <div class="col-md-4">
                                  <input id="Correo" name="Correo" type="text" placeholder="Correo" class="form-control input-md" required="">
                                    
                                  </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                <button id="submit1" name="submit1" class="btn btn-primary">SIGUIENTE</button>
                              </div>
                            </div></center>
                        </fieldset>
                      </form>                   
                  </div>
                        

                    <div id="paso2" class="tab-pane fade">
                        <legend><b><center>Realizar Prueba</center></b></legend>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="Training"><b>1.</b>¿Frase favorita?</label>
                              <div class="col-md-4"> 
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-0">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training1" id="Training1-A" value="A">
                                  A. hola
                                </label><br> 
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-1">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training1" id="Training1-B" value="B">
                                  B. Chao
                                </label><br>
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-2">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training1" id="Training1-C" value="C">
                                  C. Adios
                                </label><br>
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-3">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training1" id="Training1-D" value="D">
                                  D. Que mas
                                </label><br>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="Training"><b>2.</b>¿Mascota favorita?</label>
                              <div class="col-md-4"> 
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-0">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training2" id="Training2-A" value="A">
                                  A. Perro 
                                </label><br> 
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-1">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training2" id="Training2-B" value="B">
                                  B. Gato
                                </label><br>
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-2">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training2" id="Training2-C" value="C">
                                  C. Loro
                                </label><br>
                                <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-3">
                                  <input type="radio" name="Training2" id="Training2-D" value="D">
                                  D. Raton
                                </label><br>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group"><center>
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                <button id="submit2" name="submit2" class="btn btn-primary">SIGUIENTE</button>
                              </div></center>
                            </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div id="paso3" class="tab-pane fade">
                         <legend><b><center>Resultados Obtenidos</center></b></legend>

                         <div class="form-group"><center>
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <button id="submit3" name="submit3" class="btn btn-primary">SALIR</button>
                              </div></center>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <hr>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
    <script src="js/clean-blog.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 
         $(document).ready(function() {
              var sw ='';
              var Nombre = '';
              var Apellido ='';
              var Correo ='';
              var pregunta1= '';
              var pregunta2= '';
              $('#submit1').click(function(){ 
                  Nombre= $('input[name=Nombre]').val();
                  Apellido= $('input[name=Apellido]').val();
                  Correo= $('input[name=Correo]').val();
                  if(Nombre !== '' && Apellido !== '' && Correo !== ''){
                     if($("#Correo").val().indexOf('@', 0) == -1 || $("#Correo").val().indexOf('.', 0) == -1) {
                            alert('El correo electrónico introducido no es correcto.');
                     
                    }else{
                           alert("ir al paso 2");
                           $('.nav-tabs a[href="#paso2"]').tab('show');
                    }

                  }else{
                      console.log('Nombre: ' + Nombre);
                      console.log('Apellido: '+ Apellido);
                      console.log('Correo: ' + Correo);
                  } 
                
              });
              $('input[name=Training]').change(function(){
                  checkedSi = $( 'input[name=Training]:checked' ).val();
                    if(checkedSi === 'no')
                    {
                        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#paso2"]').tab('show');
                                            
                    }
                    
               });
               var sw='false';
               var sw2='false';   
               $('#submit2').click(function(){
                  $('input[name=Training1]').change(function(){
                     
                          pregunta1 = $( 'input[name=Training1]:checked' ).val();
                         
 
                           if(pregunta1 !== '')
                           {
                               sw= 'true';                       
                           }else{
                               sw= 'false';
                               
                           }
                     
                  }); 
                  $('input[name=Training2]').change(function(){
                     
                          pregunta2 = $( 'input[name=Training2]:checked' ).val();
                         
                           if(pregunta2 !== '')
                           {
                               sw2= 'true'; 
                                                     
                           }else{
                             
                              sw2 = 'false'; 
                           }
                     
                  });
                  if(sw=='true' && sw2=='true'){
                       $('.nav-tabs a[href="#paso3"]').tab('show');
                   }else{
                      alert('Todas las preguntas deben ser respondidas');
                   }

                     
               });
               $('#submit3').click(function(){
                    location.href ="index.html";                      
                });  
           });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Prueba de orientación profesional</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
<link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/clean-blog.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Estilos del sitio web -->
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="brand pull-left" href="#">
            <img src="http://www.politecnicojic.edu.co/images/logo/logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive logo logo-poli"> </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      Menu
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="Programas.html">Programas</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="Prueba.html">Prueba</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<br><br><br> 
 <section class="container py-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <center><h2>Prueba de Orientación Profesional</h2></center>
            <ul id="tabsJustified" class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item"><a  data-target="#paso1" class="nav-link small text-uppercase active"><b>PASO 1 - REGISTRO</b></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a data-target="#paso2" href="#paso2" class="nav-link small text-uppercase "><b>PASO 2 - PRUEBA</b></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a  data-target="#paso3" href="#paso3" class="nav-link small text-uppercase"><b>PASO 3 - RESULTADOS</b></a></li>
                <!--data-toggle="tab" ..... para ir a  los link ...  href="" -->
            </ul>
            <br>
            <div id="tabsJustifiedContent" class="tab-content">
                <div id="paso1" class="tab-pane fade active show">
                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <fieldset>

                    <!-- Form Name - si la respuesta es no permitir pasar al siguiente paso -->
                    <legend><b><center>Registrar Información</center></b></legend>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="Training"><center>¿Desea suminitrar sus datos al portal web para enviarle información en el futuro?</label>
                          <div class="col-md-4"> 
                            <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-0">
                              <input type="radio" name="Training" id="Training-0" value="si" checked="">
                              Si
                            </label> 
                            <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-1">
                              <input type="radio" name="Training" id="Training-1" value="no">
                              No
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div></center>
                        <center>

                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <!--<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Nombre">Nombre</label>-->  
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                          <input id="Nombre" name="Nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <!--<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Apellido">Apellido</label>-->  
                              <div class="col-md-4">
                              <input id="Apellido" name="Apellido" type="text" placeholder="Apellido" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                              </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <!--<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Correo">Correo</label>-->  
                              <div class="col-md-4">
                              <input id="Correo" name="Correo" type="text" placeholder="Correo" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                              </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                            <button id="submit1" name="submit1" class="btn btn-primary">SIGUIENTE</button>
                          </div>
                        </div></center>
                    </fieldset>
                  </form>                   
              </div>


                <div id="paso2" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <legend><b><center>Realizar Prueba</center></b></legend>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="Training"><b>1.</b>¿Frase favorita?</label>
                          <div class="col-md-4"> 
                            <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-0">
                              <input type="radio" name="Training1" id="Training1-A" value="A">
                              A. hola
                            </label><br> 
                            <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-1">
                              <input type="radio" name="Training1" id="Training1-B" value="B">
                              B. Chao
                            </label><br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-2">
                              <input type="radio" name="Training1" id="Training1-C" value="C">
                              C. Adios
                            </label><br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-3">
                              <input type="radio" name="Training1" id="Training1-D" value="D">
                              D. Que mas
                            </label><br>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="Training"><b>2.</b>¿Mascota favorita?</label>
                          <div class="col-md-4"> 
                            <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-0">
                              <input type="radio" name="Training2" id="Training2-A" value="A">
                              A. Perro 
                            </label><br> 
                            <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-1">
                              <input type="radio" name="Training2" id="Training2-B" value="B">
                              B. Gato
                            </label><br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-2">
                              <input type="radio" name="Training2" id="Training2-C" value="C">
                              C. Loro
                            </label><br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" for="Training-3">
                              <input type="radio" name="Training2" id="Training2-D" value="D">
                              D. Raton
                            </label><br>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group"><center>
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                            <button id="submit2" name="submit2" class="btn btn-primary">SIGUIENTE</button>
                          </div></center>
                        </div>

                </div>
                <div id="paso3" class="tab-pane fade">
                     <legend><b><center>Resultados Obtenidos</center></b></legend>

                     <div class="form-group"><center>
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <button id="submit3" name="submit3" class="btn btn-primary">SALIR</button>
                          </div></center>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<hr>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
<script src="js/clean-blog.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Funcion para obtener el valor del radiobutton y cambiar al tab siguiente 
     $(document).ready(function() {
          var sw ='';
          var Nombre = '';
          var Apellido ='';
          var Correo ='';
          var pregunta1= '';
          var pregunta2= '';
          $('#submit1').click(function(){ 
              Nombre= $('input[name=Nombre]').val();
              Apellido= $('input[name=Apellido]').val();
              Correo= $('input[name=Correo]').val();
              if(Nombre !== '' && Apellido !== '' && Correo !== ''){
                 if($("#Correo").val().indexOf('@', 0) == -1 || $("#Correo").val().indexOf('.', 0) == -1) {
                        alert('El correo electrónico introducido no es correcto.');

                }else{
                       alert("ir al paso 2");
                       $('.nav-tabs a[href="#paso2"]').tab('show');
                }

              }else{
                  console.log('Nombre: ' + Nombre);
                  console.log('Apellido: '+ Apellido);
                  console.log('Correo: ' + Correo);
              } 

          });
          $('input[name=Training]').change(function(){
              checkedSi = $( 'input[name=Training]:checked' ).val();
                if(checkedSi === 'no')
                {
                    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#paso2"]').tab('show');

                }

           });
           var sw='false';
           var sw2='false';   
           $('#submit2').click(function(){
              $('input[name=Training1]').change(function(){

                      pregunta1 = $( 'input[name=Training1]:checked' ).val();


                       if(pregunta1 !== '')
                       {
                           sw= 'true';                       
                       }else{
                           sw= 'false';

                       }

              }); 
              $('input[name=Training2]').change(function(){

                      pregunta2 = $( 'input[name=Training2]:checked' ).val();

                       if(pregunta2 !== '')
                       {
                           sw2= 'true'; 

                       }else{

                          sw2 = 'false'; 
                       }

              });
              if(sw=='true' && sw2=='true'){
                   $('.nav-tabs a[href="#paso3"]').tab('show');
               }else{
                  alert('Todas las preguntas deben ser respondidas');
               }


           });
           $('#submit3').click(function(){
                location.href ="index.html";                      
            });  
       });
</script>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [mcve] ya que al ejecutar tu código en el snippet saca errores y no saca ningún estilo por lo cual queda muy complicado poderte ayudar

Comment: en realidad esta bien el codigo, debo de montarlo bien.

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto

Comment: No entiendo porque al pegar el codigo no me lo pega completo con las etiquetas html, head, body

Comment: Cuando estés editando utiliza la herramienta que es una hoja de papel con los símbolos <>, eso te saca un popup con 4 divisiones donde podrás colocar html, css, javascript y además podrás ver en la vista previa como queda el ejejmplo

Comment: yo hago lo siguiente, le do formular pregunta y luego pego el codigo de mi .html que contiene jquery.... no veo donde esta la hoja de papel con los simboos <> ???

Comment: Esa herramienta está en la barra donde aparece la B la I y demás herramientas que facilitan la lectura del código, en la parte superior del editor de texto

Comment: ¿Puedes dar más detalles sobre tu problema? Tienes dos botones que dicen `SIGUIENTE`... ¿cuál de los dos es el que no funciona? ¿Qué sería el siguiente paso del que hablas y al cual el código debería pasar? ¿Te da algún error?

Comment: Lo que pasa esque tengo un formulario en un TAB (hay 3 tabs) , el formulario es opcional, si en el checkbox se selecciona NO, pasa al tab numero 2 donde hay una prueba--> esto me esta funcionando bien, pero cuando le usuario le da SI, yo lleno el formulario le doy al boton siguiente y no me lleva al tab numero 2, ya que me cargar la misma pagina del tab1.---> depronto aqui no se ve asi porque soy nuevo en esto y no he podido montar bien el codigo.

Comment: Si notan en el codigo de jquery esta linea $('.nav-tabs a[href="#paso2"]').tab('show');

Comment: me debe de llevar al paso 2, y me funciona con el checkbox cuando le doy no, pero cuando le da si yo valido que los campos no esten vacios y que el correo se valido---> si pasa esto le pongo esta misma linea de codigo .$('.nav-tabs a[href="#paso2"]').tab('show'); --> pero en este caso no me funciona y no se porque

Comment: Acabe de añadir una foto del primer tab --> para que lo visualicen